# Error in installing PostGIS 1.5?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, linux

I am installing PostGIS 1.5.

After giving the command ./configure, it is showing that:

> pQserverversion in -lpq not found. configure: error: could not find
>   libpq.

What does it mean?

I am using Red hat Linux (32 bit) version 5.3. PostgreSQL version 8.3.

I am working in govt. organization and I have to work on this version only when I enquired configure.log file I found this :-

```
configure:14876: result: no configure:14962: result: Using user-specified pg_config file: /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/bin/pg_config configure:14985: result: checking PostgreSQL version... PostgreSQL 8.3.23 configure:15027: checking libpq-fe.h usability configure:15027: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/include conftest.c >&5 configure:15027: $? = 0 configure:15027: result: yes configure:15027: checking libpq-fe.h presence configure:15027: gcc -E -I/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/include conftest.c configure:15027: $? = 0 configure:15027: result: yes configure:15027: checking for libpq-fe.h configure:15027: result: yes configure:15039: checking for PQserverVersion in -lpq configure:15064: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 conftest.c -lpq -L/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib -lpq >&5 /usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.0.0, needed by /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to TLSv1_method'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_set_ex_data' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_connect'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toX509_STORE_load_locations' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to BIO_free'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toBIO_ctrl' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toX509_NAME_oneline' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_verify'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toPEM_read_bio_PrivateKey' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_load_error_strings'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toX509_STORE_set_flags' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_get_peer_certificate'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toX509_get_subject_name' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_free'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toPEM_read_bio_X509' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_new' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_read'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_set_fd' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_pending'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to ENGINE_load_private_key'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toCRYPTO_num_locks' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to ERR_pop_to_mark'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to ERR_get_error'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toERR_reason_error_string' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_library_init'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toCRYPTO_set_id_callback' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_get_ex_data'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_new' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_write'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toOPENSSL_config' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_get_cert_store'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toX509_check_private_key' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to X509_free'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toERR_set_mark' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_shutdown'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toBIO_new_file' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_ctrl'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_get_error' /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to ENGINE_by_id'
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status configure:15064: $? = 1 configure: failed program was: | /* confdefs.h / | #define PACKAGE_NAME "" | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "" | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "" | #define PACKAGE_STRING "" | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "" | #define PACKAGE_URL "" | #define STDC_HEADERS 1 | #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1 | #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1 | #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1 | #define HAVE_STRING_H 1 | #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1 | #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1 | #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1 | #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1 | #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1 | #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1 | #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/" | #define POSTGIS_MAJOR_VERSION "1" | #define POSTGIS_MINOR_VERSION "5" | #define POSTGIS_MICRO_VERSION "2" | #define YYTEXT_POINTER 1 | #define HAVE_IEEEFP_H 0 | #define PWDREGRESS 1 | #define HAVE_ICONV 1 | / end confdefs.h. / | | / Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error. | Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC | builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply. */ | #ifdef __cplusplus | extern "C" | #endif | char PQserverVersion (); | int | main () | { | return PQserverVersion (); | ; | return 0; | } configure:15073: result: no configure:15083: error: could not find libpq
```

Can anyone tell me which file I am missing?

Comment: Looks like the problem is that `libpq.so` can't find `libssl.so.1.0.0`. And so you know, `libpq` is the C library for PostgreSQL. Perhaps it was installed from an RPM?

Comment: the lib file which is available in my system is libssl.so.0.9.8e. does the version of postgresql which I m using is not compatible with red hat version??? from where I can get this c library for postgresql??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need the package libpq-dev installed.

try this:

```
yum install libpq-dev
```